# SQL Server 2012 SSMS with SQL Server 2008 R2 database engine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, ssms

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 as the database engine. With my MSDN subscription, I can get SQL Server 2012 for development use. Since I noticed some cool things in 2012 SSMS, my question is that if I only use 2012 SSMS and keep 2008 R2 as the database engine, will there be any difference in scripts' generation or any other effects?

Thanks.

UPDATE 1:
Oh yes, I saw this page: [SQL Server Database Engine Backward Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143532.aspx), but it is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I am using SSMS 2012 for both SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012 engines - works flawlessly. When creating scripts, you can always define what version of SQL Server those scripts are intended for - so just pick the "right" version.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the comment. I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @marc_s BTW, your removal of sql-server tag has reduced the visibility of my question. Now instead of over 5000 people, less than 200.

Comment: Total 182 for "2008 R2", 89 for "2012" --> that's still a lot more than 200 ..... I think one should have *focused* `sql-server-xxxx` tags if only specific versions are really concerned....

Comment: FWIW - SSMS 2012 works for SQL Server 2005 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there should be no ill effects.

SSMS 2012 should generate scripts that are compatible with the database version that is being actively used.

Comment: I guess that would be correct. I just wanted to make sure that there aren't any hidden effects.